# Binary math on Number objects limited to 32 bits?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Consider the following code:

```
var combined:Number = Number(4294967296) | Number(2403025069);
var testLimit:Number = 6697992365;
trace("Combined is:", combined, "should be", testLimit);
```

Output is:

> Combined is: -1891942227 should be 6697992365

Why?! I thought Number datatypes can hold 64 bit integers (okay- really 52-bit, but the numbers above are nowhere near that limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#bitwise_OR):

> `|` bitwise OR Operator
>
> *Converts expression1 and expression2 to 32-bit unsigned integers*, and places a 1 in each bit position where the corresponding bits of either expression1 or expression2 are 1.
>
> ...
>
> The result is interpreted as a 32-bit two's complement number, so *the result is an integer* in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647.

Comment: Ewwww.... so how to do it for 64 bit? I see there are a couple BigInteger type libraries... not sure if they support bitwise OR?

Comment: n/m, created new question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758669/converting-2x32-bit-uint-number